# Python - How to pass a method as an argument to call a method from another library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass a method as an argument that will call such method from another python file as follows:

#### file2.py

```
def abc():
    return 'success.'
```

#### main.py

```
import file2
def call_method(method_name):
    #Here the method_name passed will be a method to be called from file2.py
    return file2.method_name()

print(call_method(abc))
```

What I expect is to return `success.`

If calling a method within the same file (main.py), I notice it is workable. However, for case like above where it involves passing an argument to be called from another file, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to pass the method or the method name? You're saying both. Make up your mind.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I learnt from below post that getattr() requires passing the method name in string. What if I want to pass the method directly as an argument how could it be done?

Comment: For example like the other answer shows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `getattr` to get the function from the module using a string like:

```
import file2
def call_method(method_name):
    return getattr(file2, method_name)()

print(call_method('abc'))
```